# Javascript push array of Object

Tags: javascript

I have two array and i want to merge into the single array.Here is the array.

```
var array1 = '1510207073874:File {name: "1.Login.png", lastModified: 1504530252000, lastModifiedDate: Mon Sep 04 2017 18:34:12 GMT+0530 (IST), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 34338}';
var array2 = '151020704875:File {name: "1.Login.png", lastModified: 1504530252000, lastModifiedDate: Mon Sep 04 2017 18:34:12 GMT+0530 (IST), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 34338}';
```

I want to merge these two array into single array like:

```
var array3 = '1510207073874:File {name: "1.Login.png", lastModified: 1504530252000, lastModifiedDate: Mon Sep 04 2017 18:34:12 GMT+0530 (IST), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 34338},
'151020704875:File {name: "1.Login.png", lastModified: 1504530252000, lastModifiedDate: Mon Sep 04 2017 18:34:12 GMT+0530 (IST), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 34338}';
```

Comment: No array appears at code at Question

Comment: Neither the input nor output is a valid array or an object. They are just strings.

Comment: sorry i have string with objects.how can i merge into single variable.

Comment: this isn't even a valid stringify json

Answer (score -1):

First of all what u want is not a merge but it is simple a join. I think it can be done just using the "+" operator to concatenate two arrays into one array.In javascript arrays are objects.

```
var array3=array1 + array2;
```

[see image for more clearity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLkZf.png)